# how to make hashtags with regex in php? for texts or usernames containing (-) or (.)?

Tags: php, regex

```
$post = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, htmlspecialchars($_POST['post']));
$pat = array('/#(\w+)/', '/@(\w+)/');
$rep = array('<a href="#">#$1</a>','<a href="profile.php?user=$1">@$1</a>');
$post = preg_replace($pat, $rep, $post);
```

above regex code works for on texts without (`.`) and (`-`). I want which can support with `#stack-overflow` `#stack.overflow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regular expression so it includes `.` and `-`:

```
$pat = array('/#([-.\w]+)/', '/@([-.\w]+)/');
```

You might want to not allow it to end with `.`, though, in case the hashtag is at the end of a #sentence.

```
$pat = array('/#([-.\w]*[-\w])/', '/@([-.\w]*[-\w])/');
```